# Solve this equation $3^{(x-3)^{(x+3)}} = (3x+2)^{(x-3)}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Please can someone help with step by step solving of this equation?

Solve

$$3^{(x-3)^{(x+3)}} = (3x+2)^{(x-3)},$$
for x

Thanks
A

Comment: Hi. You should show what you have done and what is causing you troubles to solve your problem.

Comment: What does stop you from approaching this question?

Answer (score 2):

As Caife answered, $x=3$ is a trivial solution.

However, taking logarithms and graphing the functions $$f(x)=\log \left(3^{(x-3)^{(x+3)}}\right)\qquad \qquad g(x)=\log \left((3 x+2)^{(x-3)}\right)$$ there is another intersection just above $x=4$ but I suspect that only numerical methods will allow you to find its exact value. Using Newton methods (have fun with the derivatives), the solution is almost $x=4.15532$.

Taking into acount the *algebra-precalculus* tag, I do not suppose that they expect you to find this one. If you are interested in the manner we can get it, just let me know.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for solutions in the integers, note that $3^{(x-3)^{(x+3)}}$ is a power of $3$, so also $(3x+2)^{(x-3)}$ must be a power of $3$.

On the other hand, $3x+2$ is not divisible by $3$ if $x$ is an integer, so the only possibility is when both sides are $1$. Thus $x=3$ is the only integral solution.

I see no easy algebraic method for determining non integral solutions and I doubt there is one.

Comment: I wonder if, building the problem, they noticed that there is the second root not so far away from the trivial solution.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici Probably not, but we'd need more information about the source of the problem.

Answer (score -1):

Try substituting $x=3$. Certainly solves it!